How to set the default selected item in GridControl/Winform to 'none'
I have a GridControl form with data in it. When I start the application, the first row in my GridControl row is selected. I don't want this, what should I do?
I do not select items when I run the application.

Per the DevExpress Documentation:
If you want the Grid to have no focused row, call the FocusInvalidRow() method.
